# AUPreset reference to caf files in Documents folder in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, caf

I have a AUPreset that references multiple CAF files. The AUPreset file-references is pointing to file://localhost//Library/Audio/Sounds/file.caf since file.caf has been inserted into my XCode project creating folder references. This way everythings works fine.

The problem I'm having is that I need to download this caf file from the internet and when I do this I save it in my Documents folder. Now I don't know what path to have in my AUPreset file so it references the caf files correctly.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to create a Sounds folder inside Documents and place all the CAF files in that folder. This way the AUPreset locates the files automatically.